Serializacion de XML a una clase que no sea instanciable por el cliente
Estoy deserializando un XML a una clase en una librería de C#. Esa clase tiene una propiedad de otra clase, que no quiero que sea instanciable por el cliente final.
¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?
Esta es la clase de ejemplo ( acortada para no dar informacion irrelevante):
    public class Archivo : IClaseBasePer
    {

        private string idField;

        private List<IdiomaValor> listaDescripcionField;

        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return idField;
            }
            set
            {
                idField = value;
            }
        }

        public List<IdiomaValor> ListaDescripcion
        {
            get
            {
                return listaDescripcionField;
            }
            set
            {
                listaDescripcionField = value;
            }
        }
}
    public  class IdiomaValor
    {

        private string langField;

        private string valueField;

        public string Lang
        {
            get
            {
                return langField;
            }
            set
            {
                langField = value;
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

No quiero que el cliente pueda hacer new IdiomaValor(), pero quiero que pueda ver Archivo.ListaDescripcion()
Probé con ìnternal en la clase IdiomaValor, pero dice que no vale, por temas de que es mas restrictivo la clase que la propiedad.

Dependerá de la librería utilizada para la deserialización. Entenderás que si la librería utilizada, lo que hace internamente es instanciar las clases necesarias, lo que tu solicitas es imposible.
El XmlSerializer nativo de C# funciona de otra manera, por lo que te permite hacer lo que tu necesitas. Para esto debes colocar como private el constructor de la clase que no quieres que sea posible instanciar (es el mismo "truco" que se utiliza en los Singletons)
Ejemplo:
Nota: Quité el List para facilitar el ejemplo
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml= """<Archivo><listaDescripcionField><Lang>es</Lang></listaDescripcionField></Archivo>""";
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Archivo));
        var r = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml)) as Archivo;
    }
}

public class Archivo
{
    public IdiomaValor listaDescripcionField { get; set; }
}
public class IdiomaValor
{
    private IdiomaValor() { } //Constructor privado
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}


Por otro lado, me parece algo extraño lo que necesitas. El único caso de uso que se me ocurre es que no quieres que sea posible volver a setear la propiedad, es decir que esto no se pueda hacer:
Archivo.ListaDescripcion = new List<IdiomaValor>(); //que esto no se pueda hacer

Si este fuera el caso, solo debes cambiar el modificador de la propiedad de set a init
public List<IdiomaValor> ListaDescripcion { get; init;}


Como comentario final, tu código tiene demasiado tufo a java. Por ejemplo la clase IdiomaValor en C# es sencillamente:
public class IdiomaValor
{
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


Gracias @Yussef. LA idea de esto, es que el cliente no va a usar la clase idioma valor para nada que no sea leer algo ya escrito. Por lo que quiero evitar que pueda ver la clase en Intelliseense o lo que sea.
Lo del tufo a Java, pues no me digas. Lo crea asi VSStudio (pegar XML como clases) y me suena que en la doc de MS tambien lo he visto asi (propiedades privadas y publicas)
